# /usr/bin/pdflatex (file fa5free0solid): Font fa5free0solid at 54 0 not found for LIPICS-2021

Tags: pdftex, tex-core, fontawesome5

I am using the [LIPICS template](https://submission.dagstuhl.de/documentation/authors#) and compiling using `pdflatex` on Ubuntu-18.04.
I have the `fontawesome5` installed and all, but the compilation fails with the error in the subject. I wonder, first, how to fix this problem -- where to start looking at things? Second, a minor question, did anyone compile LIPICS templated-documents using `Xe/Lua-LaTeX`? (For I think the latter are more "clever" with the fonts.)

This proves I do have the files:

```
ls /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/fontawesome5
FontAwesome5Brands-Regular-400.otf  
FontAwesome5Free-Regular-400.otf  
FontAwesome5Free-Solid-900.otf
```

Maybe the output from `pdflatex main.tex` is of any help:

```
{/usr/share/texmf/fonts/enc/dvips/lm/lm-rmtt.enc}{/usr/share/texmf/fonts/enc/dv
ips/lm/lm-ec.enc}{/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/base/8r.enc}
kpathsea: Running mktexpk --mfmode / --bdpi 600 --mag 0+540/600 --dpi 540 fa5free0solid
mktexpk: don't know how to create bitmap font for fa5free0solid.
mktexpk: perhaps fa5free0solid is missing from the map file.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.
```

EDIT: I checked the same commands on another Ubuntu-18.04 box, and now it complains about `fa5free0regular`.

Comment: What exactly have to installed? I never use LaTeX from Debian/Ubuntu as it is very fragmented into many different Ubuntu/Debian packages (different from latex packages). I use the upsteam TeXLive instead, which installs **everything**. I just did a search for awesome in my LaTeX installation it found both `otf` (which I do not think `pdflatex` supports) and Type1 (`pfb`) whic `pdflatex` do support. So I ask again, exactly what did you install on your system?

Comment: @Ilonpilaaja Run `sudo updmap-sys --enable Map=fontawesome5.map`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Problem with fontawesome5 / Texlive Ubuntu18.04](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/497792/problem-with-fontawesome5-texlive-ubuntu18-04)

Comment: @MarcelKrüger, thank you sooo much! This: `sudo updmap-sys --enable Map=fontawesome5.map` fixed it instantly! To answer @daleif's question: I use `texlive-full`, "of course", since I thought this is "standard" for Ubuntu. Right now, thanks to Marcel's solution, I can postpone the move to Ubuntu 20.04, and thanks -- will look for the "upstream TeXLive" when I do so!

Comment: @Ilonpilaaja good, a lot of Ubuntu users don't, hence why I asked.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the problem was solved by updating the font map properly.